# Jquery UI modal dialog using MVC structure

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm using a Zend framework to create a Jquery UI dialog with a submit button to add something to a MYSQL database. My code works when using a normal URL (/index), but when it's on a custom route page (/addpost/new), it doesn't seem to work. Anyone know what the problem is?

JQUERY DIALOG

```
<script>


$(function() {

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
        .button()
        .click(function() {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
});
</script>
```

BUTTON

```
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

FORM

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
<form id="form-id">
<fieldset>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" class="text ui-widget- content ui-corner-all" />
<input type="submit" value="Add to Database">
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

JQUERY SUBMIT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#form-id').submit(function() {
$.ajax(
{
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/addtodatabase',
    data: $(this).serializeArray(),
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      //code
      }
      });
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: whats the exact problem you are having?

Comment: the data is not connecting with the database. The url (/addtodatabase) connects to the database and inserts info into the Mysql database. It works with a normal URL route (/index), but not with a custom one.

Comment: so this custom URL you speak of, is it an actual file in your directory? It obviously will not work if it isn't a real file on your server.

Comment: it's a real file. Not exactly sure if it's a custom route problem, but it's fine with something like (example.com/index) but not with (example.com/addinfo/username) - the jquery works in terms of the dialog opens, but for some reason it's not directing it to the URL after the submit..

Answer (score 0):

If you can save it on the index page your code is fine.

Check the ajax request in firebug and see where the the request is being sent to. Most likey its a context issue. To get around this test it in firebug by calling it directly:

`$.ajax({url: "/addpost/new"}, {})`

Change the url param above until you hit your endpoint. That should sort it.

:)